# How to know if app is not running when launchOptions includes UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

During my testing it appears that launchOptions includes UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey under 2 circumstances.

1. The app is not running at all (app has been swiped killed)
2. App is in the background but in a "suspended" state.

How can I accurately determine which of these 2 states the app was in when it is launched by location services and has the launchOption key "UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey"?

Comment: Which app delegate method are you referring to?

Comment: application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

Comment: That delegate method will not be called in your 2nd circumstance. It's only called when the app is fully launched, not simply returned from the background.

Comment: I promise it is.  Im setting up local notifications on the phone if UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey is present in that method.  And several times i've gotten the notification when the app was still in the background.  Double tap home button, and its still there.  I should only ever get that notification if the app is completely killed.

Comment: Look at "Execution States for Apps" on this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW6
I need to determine the difference between "Not Running" and "Suspended"